# was bought vs. has been bought

Tags: past-tense

What is the correct way to say this:

- The launch was successful and the company was bought by a competitor 2 years after I left.

or

- The launch was successful and the company has been bought by a competitor 2 years after I left.

Comment: One event localized at one point in the past - _was bought_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially written as a comment, expanded to an answer.

Let us break down the sentence.

Sequence 1

1. The launch was successful
2. I left the company many years ago
3. The company was bought by a competitor 2 years after I left

In this sequence these sentences would both be correct

```
The launch was successful and the company was bought by a competitor 2 years after I left.

The launch was successful and the company has been bought by a competitor 2 years after I left.
```

Sequence 2

1. The launch was successful
2. I left the company only 2+ years ago
3. The company was bought by a competitor recently (2 years after I left)

In this sequence these sentences would both be correct. Note that the second sentence can be rephrased with the addition of the word "recently" to convey a clearer message to the reader/listener.

```
The launch was successful and the company was bought by a competitor 2 years after I left.

The launch was successful and the company has been (recently) bought by a competitor 2 years after I left.
```

Which sequence describes your scenario better?